# Batching large result sets using Rx

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I've got an interesting question for Rx experts. I've a relational table keeping information about events. An event consists of id, type and time it happened. In my code, I need to fetch all the events within a certain, potentially wide, time range.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event.time > :before AND event.time < :after ORDER        BY time LIMIT :batch_size
```

To improve reliability and deal with large result sets, I query the records in batches of size :batch_size. Now, I want to write a function that, given :before and :after, will return an Observable representing the result set.

```
Observable<Event> getEvents(long before, long after);
```

Internally, the function should query the database in batches. The distribution of events along the time scale is unknown. So the natural way to address batching is this:
    fetch first N records
    if the result is not empty, use the last record's time as a new 'before' parameter, and fetch the next N records; otherwise terminate
    if the result is not empty, use the last record's time as a new 'before' parameter, and fetch the next N records; otherwise terminate
    ... and so on (the idea should be clear)

My question is:

**Is there a way to express this function in terms of higher-level Observable primitives** (filter/map/flatMap/scan/range etc), without using the subscribers explicitly?

So far, I've failed to do this, and come up with the following straightforward code instead:

```
private void observeGetRecords(long before, long after, Subscriber<? super Event> subscriber) {
    long start = before;
    while (start < after) {
        final List<Event> records;
        try {
            records = getRecordsByRange(start, after);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
            return;
        }
        if (records.isEmpty()) break;
        records.forEach(subscriber::onNext);
        start = Iterables.getLast(records).getTime();
    }

    subscriber.onCompleted();
}

public Observable<Event> getRecords(final long before, final long after) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> observeGetRecords(before, after, subscriber));
}
```

Here, getRecordsByRange implements the SELECT query using DBI and returns a List. This code works fine, but lacks elegance of high-level Rx constructs.

NB: I know that I can return Iterator as a result of SELECT query in DBI. However, I don't want to do that, and prefer to run multiple queries instead. This computation does not have to be atomic, so the issues of transaction isolation are not relevant.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you'd want to continue from the time of the last batch. given tstart, tend, if the data in this range ends at tdata, why would you want to query from tdata? There aren't any data available between tdata and tend at this point.

Comment: So this is why I check whether 'records' list is empty, and break from the loop, if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't fully understand why you want such time-reuse, here is how I'd do it:

```
BehaviorSubject<Long> start = BehaviorSubject.create(0L);

start
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
.flatMap(tstart -> 
    getEvents(tstart, tstart + twindow)
    .publish(o -> 
         o.takeLast(1)
         .doOnNext(r -> start.onNext(r.time))
         .ignoreElements()
         .mergeWith(o)
    )
)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I should definitely look into Subjects, have not used them before.

Comment: BTW what do you mean by time-reuse? I just want to batch SQL queries in a way that is opaque to the client of the getRecords function.

Comment: I meant you use the output of the query to parametrize the next query.